# Angularjs - Lifecycle of a view

Tags: android, ios, angularjs

I'm a native mobile developer so I use to do my work with android java and objective-c iOs.
So I always tend to work with a lifecycle of activity or viewcontroller in mind. And broadcastreceivers and localnotifications to refresh the views on the fly.

Now I have to develop with angularJS and looks promise, but I use to fall in novice design errors.

What is the equivalent on angularJS in terms of a view of:

- onCreate
- onResume
- onPause
- Services and boradcastreceivers as in Android

Can I follow this approach or I must switch my mind?

Comment: you can use ui-router which will give you lifecycle events like `beforeTransition` and `afterTransition`.

Comment: @ashfaq.p yeah, i'm using ui-router. There is something similar to local notifications?

Comment: For what purpose you want local notifications?? This will help me to understand your need better.

Comment: @ashfaq.p was a typo, i mean delegates(ios) or broadcasts(Android).

Comment: I believe you can tap on the events and keep listeners and trigger them manually.